# random forest error- Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [80, 1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have built a random forest model using sklearn and python, and I want to now use my model to predict the label from new data, not with the data the model was created on. Is there a way to do this? My original dataset has 400 rows, and my test data is 20% of this, or 80 rows. I want to be able to predict the value of just one row of new feature values. I have attached a sample of what my original data looks like, and the new data I would like to input. I keep getting the error

```
     raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [80, 1]
```

Is this because I have 80 rows in my test data and 1 in the data I want the predictions for?

sample of what original data looks like, except there are 400 rows
[image]
data I want to be inputted below:
[image]
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi emily123, could you edit the question and provide some code on how you're calling the model with a single row of data? It would help us find a solution to your problem much faster.

Comment: I think I figured it out, thank you!